FastAPI upload file using path into S3 with bucket name and path as query parameters
I'm building a FastAPI endpoint to upload a file into a S3 bucket with bucket name and path as input parameters. When I don't specify the file path, the file is getting uploaded successfully. But when i mention the path, the file is not getting uploaded. Please help me to fix this issue.
#upload.py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, HTTPException, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError, PartialCredentialsError, ClientError
import boto3
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "XXX"
AWS_SECRET_KEY = "YYY"
AWS_REGION_NAME = "ap-northeast-1"


# Pydantic model for the request body
class S3UploadRequest(BaseModel):
    bucket_name: str
    file_path: Optional[str] = None  # Make file_path optional


@app.post("/upload/")
async def upload_file_to_s3(
        s3_request: S3UploadRequest = Depends(),
        file: UploadFile = File(...)
):
    """
    Upload a file to an S3 bucket.

    :param s3_request: S3UploadRequest. Contains the bucket name and file path.
    :param file: UploadFile. The file to upload.
    """
    try:
        s3_client = boto3.client(
            's3',
            aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
            aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY,
            region_name=AWS_REGION_NAME
        )

        # Set default file path if not provided
        if s3_request.file_path is None:
            s3_request.file_path = file.filename

        # Upload file to S3
        s3_client.upload_fileobj(file.file, s3_request.bucket_name, s3_request.file_path)

        return {
            "message": f"File '{file.filename}' uploaded successfully to bucket '{s3_request.bucket_name}' at '{s3_request.file_path}'"}

    except NoCredentialsError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="AWS credentials not found.")
    except PartialCredentialsError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Incomplete AWS credentials.")
    except ClientError as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app='upload:app', reload=True)


Does it raizs any errors?

@ParmanM.Alizadeh - Thanks much for the response. I dont see any error in the logs and as per logs i get successful code 200 printing the return statement. However in the aws S3 console, I see a file named '/'(folder type is blank but the icon refers to file). I doubt if there could any permission issue but I'm able to upload files into the same path via AWS console.

You might find this answer, as well as we this answer and this answer helpful.
